# How to configure Amazon Linux ec2 instance for java heap size?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, heap-memory

I created an ec2 instance which have java maxHeapSize = 2g by default. Then I deploy my spring boot application on it. I want to increase heap size to 3g.
I tried all this methods but no result

```
1. Add in Elastic Beanstalk -> Configuration -> Software - > Environment properties -> _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms3g
2. Create Procfile.txt and write in it "web: java -Xms3g -jar project.jar". Zip it with .jar file and deploy on instance.
```

Is there any other method that I should try?

Comment: Are you running [Tomcat on Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html)? See [Java with Tomcat platform options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-java).

Answer (score 0):

Add xmx property in your dockerfile.

EX:

```
$ java -Xmx3g your_jar
```

also, you can set heap size through env variables

by setting the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in my ECS Task Definition like this:

| Environment Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS | -XX:InitialHeapSize=1g -XX:MaxHeapSize=3g |

I hope this helps!
also, you might make a startup script which can help to automate it.